# Is it possible to find a "share" action on Facebook JSON data?

Tags: facebook, json

I normally get Facebook JSON data that look like this (taken from an example):

```
 {    "data": [
      {
         "id": "X999_Y999",
         "from": {
            "name": "Tom Brady", "id": "X12"
         },
        ........
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000",
         "updated_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000"
      }    ] }
```

}

Anyway, I want to find "Share" click-actions in Facebook, that is, the actions specifically created by users who clicked the "share this link" button.

1) It appears that the API does not explicitly encode such actions...

2) However, they are explicit: Facebook SHARE functions are different than "likes", "comments", "wall posts", "tags", "image postings", etc....

3) How can I parse whether or not a Facebook action was, indeed, Shared from a standard Facebook JSON data array?

4) Is there a way to determine if X shared an action by Y ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) It appears that the API does not explicitly encode such actions...**

> Clicking the "share" button triggers annotation of a post with the
>   "Links" facebook    application ... implicitly conveying the fact that
>   a share action was executed. Thus, if   we see that a post act is
>   associated with an "application" field, then we can know that   the
>   user indeed was "sharing" the link content when creating this post.

**2) However, they are explicit: Facebook SHARE functions are different than "likes", "comments", "wall posts", "tags", "image postings", etc....**

> YES share actions ARE different then likes : They are created by a
>   different   application, and also, the convey a specificity of the
>   type of user action.

**3) How can I parse whether or not a Facebook action was, indeed, a "Share" from a standard Facebook JSON data array?**

> You can implement the parsing logic of (1) by scanning the JSON map  for a
>   "application"   field, which contains a "id" key, that has
>   value  of "2309869772" - this is the ID of the   facebook "Links"
>   action.
>
> This can be seen in the json as such :
>
> "application": {
>                "name": "Links",
>                "id": "2309869772"
>             },
>
> Of course, there are other shares, for example... a sharing of a
>   photo.  This is also a   link, but it is conveyed differently.  This
>   can be seen in the following share action   snippet, wherein somebody
>   shared a photo created by jay vyas :
>
> "properties": [
>                {
>                   "name": "By",
>                   "text": "Jay Vyas",
>                   "href": "http://www.facebook.com/jvyas1"
>                }
>             ],

**4) SADLY : It appears that, share actions don't directly link to the social action created by a facebook user.  For example, if X shares a url that Y Posted ---**

> a) the url will get replicated X's post**
>
> b) we cannot directly extract the particular id of Y's post which X
>   shared.**
>
> Thus : I surmise the following : we cannot create a network of
>   personal relationships      and shared content using the current
>   facebook API.

I would certainly appreciate other answers or insights to these thoughts...